# why my code throwing NZEC error python3 in SPOJ

Tags: python, python-3.x

the same logic in CPP is working perfectly fine  but I am stuck with this solution now.

```
coun = int(input())
for ki in range(coun):
    val = input().split()
    j = 2
    ans = int(val[0])
    for value in val:
        if(value == '*'):
            ans = ans * int(val[j])
            if(j<=len(val)):
                j = j+2
        if(value == '/'):
            ans = ans / int(val[j])
            if(j<=len(val)):
                j = j+2
        if(value == '+'):
            ans = ans + int(val[j])
            if(j<=len(val)):
                j = j+2
        if(value == '-'):
            ans = ans - int(val[j])
            if(j<=len(val)):
                j = j+2
        if(value == '%'):
            ans = ans % int(val[j])
            if(j<=len(val)):
                j = j+2         
        if(value == '='):
            break
    #res.append(ans)
    print(ans)
```

this code here is logically correct but I am unable to find the reason for the NZEC error.

Comment: Well... for one thing, it's not properly indented. If you're not sure how to properly format code in SO posts, edit your question, delete the code, repaste it from your source, then select the entire code block and type Ctrl+K or click the `{}` button in the editor interface.

Comment: @glibdud is it okay now?

Comment: `NZEC` stands for "non-zero exit code". Usually happens when your script gets terminated by an uncaught exception.

Comment: Why did you tag this `python-3.x`? You're using `raw_input`; that's Python 2, not 3.

Comment: Which SPOJ problem is this solving?